What are the meanings of these functions in the annular fin equations?
I'm an engineering student building an excel calculator for annular heatsinks based on the annular fin equations and a variety of experimentally derived functions for convective heat transfer coefficient h.
The Wikipedia page for annular fins shows this formula:
Equation from Wikipedia Annular Fins page
I have never seen these C2K1( ) and C1I1( ) functions before, are these some sort of bessel function?
Thanks in advance for any advice here, I've tried having a look at the sources for this page however my university library does not hold the textbook cited.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annular_fin
This is the wikipedia page I am referring to.

I suspect that $K_1$ and $I_1$ are modified Bessel functions of the first and second kinds and $C_2$ and $C_1$ are constants (which might correspond to initial or boundary conditions for the differential equation).  But it seems to me that it's a poorly written Wikipedia page for not explaining that.

Hi Robert Israel This was the case I think, I managed to find more information in "Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer" by FRANK P. INCROPERA.
As you have said it is unfortunately not the best written Wikipedia page.
Thanks!
